# Why do some devices seemingly need the wifi router to reboot before they can connect?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I've noticed a pattern but I'm not sure if it's a crappy router, crappy wireless device, or maybe everything is working as intended.

I can wirelessly connect my office PC to the router's settings page for a day, maybe two, then afterwards I can't anymore until it's reset.

Unrelated, but similar, in various places that offer free wifi, my kindle will connect fine most days, but occasionally won't unless the router is reset. After the reset, I connect ok.

What's happening behind the scenes that makes a router stop allowing you to connect? Is it something on my end that's changing, or on the router's end?

Comment: I would blame the rounter until such time its replaced and this is still a problem.

Comment: @CreeDorofl: It's difficult to diagnose something like this without more information. When you say you can't connect to "the router's settings page" what error are you getting and are other network functions unavailable? What model is your router. How strong is the signal? Can other devices connect? What mode are you using (e.g. 802.11b/g)

Comment: @James hi, thanks for the reply. Think it was http error "Empty reply from server", I'll confirm tomorrow. No password prompt. Router continues to work (I can access local server and internet, using wired or wireless PCs). Just can't access the settings page anymore, tested w/2 PCs. And the kindle can no longer connect to it. I haven't tried connecting with any other device. Signal's strong, it's just across the hall, DL at 2+ MB/S. Rebooting via unplug/replug fixes it immediately. In restaurants etc if my Kindle can't connect, same reboot fix works, so I'm wondering if all routers do this.

Comment: I am curious, why do you need to access the settings page regularly? If you are changing settings it could be that it causing your problem. Also, many routers reboot themselves every time you change the configuration.

Comment: @James yup, it reboots after every settings change. That's no problem, I stay connected (or reconnect) just fine after that happens. I do routine network stuff, forwarding ports as new apps or games get installed, setting up vnc for people, checking the IPs of temporarily connected devices, or printers. I've had a few people tell me "you shouldn't be playing with those settings anyway" and others tell me "you should only use a wired connection to change those settings". I'm hoping I don't hear more of that. I'm only interested in why this basic functionality breaks on my router after X hours.

Comment: @CreeDorofl: Have you tried upgrading the router firmware to the latest version? You still haven't said what model it is, but if you still have problems with the latest version of the official firmware then it may be possible to install a third-party firmware, e.g. dd-wrt.

Comment: @James oops, where's my head? It's a linksys WRT54G. I'll look into fresh firmware... how long does that typically take? It's an office environment so I'm hoping to minimize downtime.

Comment: @CreeDorofl: It shouldn't take long to do it - maybe 5 minutes or something. I would recommend the manufacturer's own firmware first since it should be less risky, and please be careful to download the right one for that exact model as otherwise it may be possible to 'brick' the router.